# Winnings on Stated Odds

Tags: probability

My book asks:

If the odds of the Broncos beating the Dolphins is 5 to 4, and you bet $10 on the Broncos, how much do you stand to win?

and the answer is...$8.

I can't follow.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of expressing fractional odds,
odds in favor, and odds against.

Here $5:4$ are odds in favor of Broncos, which means that

if you bet $5$ on the Broncos, and Broncos win, your stake of $\$5$ will be returned + $\$4$

thus if you bet $\$10$, you will be returned $\$(10+8)$
so your "win" = net winning is $\$8$

**Note**

UK betting odds are expressed as odds against which are possibly easier to understand, specially if expressed as  $x:1$, which means that for every 1 unit bet, you will receive (stake of $1$ *plus* $x$) [Easier to understand because the net winnings stares at you as the first figure.]

Comment: Mag-NIFICENT! T H A N K  Y O U ! ! ! : )  )  )

Comment: @Dibliander3000: Glad to be of help ! $\;\;$ :)